# worklight app not working on real android phone

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a hybrid application in Ibm worklight using jquerymobile framework. The application accesses external database hosted on my own domain (www.blueocean5.com) through php script. It works fine on Ibm worklight console as well as on AVD. But when I tried to run the application from real android phone, it won't work. I googled and found that the Ibm worklight apps first go to intermediate worklight server and then to external hosted server. In the worklight app settings on android phone, it wants some server URL. I don't understand that. Please help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most definitely need to first learn about Worklight:

- [IBM Worklight training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/).

You provide pretty much no information to work with in your question... I am guessing then that the problem is that the device and the computer that hosts the Worklight Server (Eclipse with Worklight Studio installed) are not on the same network, thus the app fails connecting to the Worklight Server. [validated via the comments below]

Comment: I think there is no need to display code because my application works fine. There is no code problem. As you asked "Do the device and computer where Eclipse (= Worklight Studio, your Worklight Development Server) is installed, connected to the same wifi network?". Yes, and then application works fine in the android phone. But I want to know, what happens when I want to use app from any random location(home, college, etc.), Is there a need to install the webspere server online on some domain.

Comment: This is entirely based on the needs of your application. If you intend on using features such as: adapters, push notifications, direct update, remote disable, jsonstore (with sync), etc... the application must be able to connect to the Worklight Server; in a real production environment there will be a Worklight Server in the architecture.

Comment: I don't understand -in a real production environment there will be a Worklight Server in the architecture.

Comment: Worklight is intended mostly for enterprise companies, insurance companies, banks, etc... The features I mentioned rely on the existence of a Worklight server in your Production environment - the infrastructure, servers, services, backends, etc... which operate everything; If you do not understand all of this, then perhaps you should explain what you are looking for. Are you a company or a student or small business, or... what?

Comment: It means I can't do anything. I have developed the application upto 60% for my final year project. What do I do to overcome this problem. My sir told me that this problem can be solved by installing the worklight server in my domain, and give the URL to that ip in the worklight app settings in the app running on real android device. Is this correct?

Comment: Okay, so you're a student. It is possible to install Worklight on an application server, but this is available only to customers who purchased a license to use Worklight. It is illegal to use the Developer Edition for consumer purposes. In your case you will need to keep Eclipse running in a computer that is open to external connections; When eclipse is running with Worklight Studio installed, it functions as the Worklight Server, hence its name - Worklight Development Server.

Comment: You will need to configure the development server with these settings, the ip and port used for external connections. With this set in your server, the next time you build the app, it will use these same settings and should be able to connect.

Comment: I understand that but I have to submit the android app in the IBM TGMC competition 2014 whose deadline coming closer ie. 28th of january. So, what I do? Please guide me.

Comment: This is a competition, no? You wrote the code, now configure your computer. Only you can do this. Figure out how to enable your computer to be accessible from the outside via public Internet, and then configure the server IP and port accordingly: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devenv/t_changing_the_port_number_of_th.html

Comment: And please educate yourself on how to ask questions. If you want help, provide all details instead of dragging a long conversation which could have been much shorter had you just taken a minute to explain your situation.

Comment: Ok! I am a newbie in this kind of environment. I tried to learn more and ask questions in a better way from now on.

Comment: Good luck with the competition; this question is answered... please mark as answered when possible.